# How can I encode and decode an Array of Numbers in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber, nscoding

I'm creating a class which will store the statistics for my game.  I'd like to store each round score into a mutable array which can be persisted and written to file.

I'm using the NSCoding protocol and implementing the encodeWithCoder and initWithCoder Methods.

```
#define masteredComponentsKey @"masteredComponents"
#define scoresKey   @"scores"
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeObject:_masteredComponents forKey:masteredComponentsKey];
    [encoder encodeObject:_scores forKey:scoresKey];

}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _masteredComponents = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:masteredComponentsKey];
        _scores = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:scoresKey];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Since arrays are pointers to objects in Objective-C, I figure my scores need to be an Object-Wrapped integer such as an NSNumber or NSValue.  However, these Objects don't implement NSCoding Protocol.

So what's the best way to persist a bunch of numbers using NSCoding?

***----This is my first StackOverflow post so please excuse any unusual decorum----***

Comment: I would recommend the `NSArray` methods `writeToFile:atomically:` and `arrayWithContentsOfFile:` methods for writing an array to a file/reading an array from a file.

Comment: That's a good thought and I had considered using writeToFile:atomically. The problem being I would like the flexibility of saving and restoring primitive data types such as int, BOOL, double.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSValue` and `NSNumber` implement `NSCoding` protocol so you can use them ..

`NSValue` implementes `NSSecureCoding` which is inherited from `NSCoding`, look at the [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSValue)

So you can use them:

```
[encoder encodeObject:@(_scores) forKey:scoresKey];
...
_scores = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:scoresKey] intValue];
```

Comment: ah yes that was sitting right there in the documentation.  The one thing I will point out to anyone using your code sample, the encodeObject can be simply referred to as _scores.  Thanks for the info!